# puppet does not work over openvpn: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server

Tags: networking, openvpn, puppet

We have a network 10.10.0.0/24, and one of the hosts (server0, 10.10.0.123) have puppetmaster installed. Others are connecting to it and everything seems fine.

Another one host (server1) is on another network and have openvpn connection to to puppetmaster host, openvpn network is 192.168.124.0/24 (192.168.124.1 - server0, 192.168.124.6 - server1).

Everything was working some time ago, but  now when I'm trying to run puppet on server1 it fails with no message:

```
/usr/sbin/puppetd --no-daemonize --debug -o --server server0.fqdn
<...>
debug: Loaded state in 0.00 seconds
debug: Using cached certificate for ca
debug: Using cached certificate for server1
debug: Using cached certificate_revocation_list for ca
debug: catalog supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml marshal pson raw yaml; using pson
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: 
info: Not using expired catalog for server1 from cache; expired at Fri May 27 15:56:15 +0300 2011
notice: Using cached catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Can't understand what am I missing. Telnet to puppet port works fine, as well as http. I've tried to connect to both 192.168.124.X and 10.10.0.X ips.

Here is the routing table to server1:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.124.1   192.168.124.5   255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
192.168.124.5   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.10.0.0       192.168.124.5   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.X    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

tcpdump of connection attempt:

```
15:44:17.556745 IP 192.168.124.6.59261 > 192.168.124.1.8140: S 3630206975:3630206975(0) win 5840 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 333953908 0,nop,wscale 7>
15:44:17.938407 IP 192.168.124.1.8140 > 192.168.124.6.59261: S 3687729362:3687729362(0) ack 3630206976 win 5792 <mss 1366,sackOK,timestamp 3325304835 333953908,nop,wscale 7>
15:44:17.938417 IP 192.168.124.6.59261 > 192.168.124.1.8140: . ack 1 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 333954290 3325304835>
15:44:17.939187 IP 192.168.124.6.59261 > 192.168.124.1.8140: P 1:106(105) ack 1 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 333954291 3325304835>
15:44:18.274663 IP 192.168.124.1.8140 > 192.168.124.6.59261: F 1:1(0) ack 1 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 3325305329 333954290>
15:44:18.274893 IP 192.168.124.6.59261 > 192.168.124.1.8140: F 106:106(0) ack 2 win 46 <nop,nop,timestamp 333954626 3325305329>
15:44:18.533685 IP 192.168.124.1.8140 > 192.168.124.6.59261: R 3687729363:3687729363(0) win 0
15:44:18.753026 IP 192.168.124.1.8140 > 192.168.124.6.59261: R 3687729364:3687729364(0) win 0
```

Why does it resets connection?

There's nothing in puppetmaster log, even when running with -d switch.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Run puppet master in `--no-daemonize --debug` mode and see what it says.

Comment: Nothing about this host :(

Answer (score 1):

Did you put the `192.168.124.0/24` network inside `fileserver.conf`? Also, are you sure date&time on client and server are reasonably synchronized?

Oh, I just noticed the server is natted! You said `server0`'s IP is 10.10.0.123, but the connection is being made to 192.168.124.1 according to the dump. This might cause the server certificate to be rejected.

If I were you, I'd make sure to connect to the non-natted IP, and also make sure that the name of the puppet server matches its non-natted IP, *and* that the reverse of the IP matches the name.

Use a different name for the OpenVPN IP.

Comment: Yes, vpn network added to fileserver.conf. Date/time is synced, but servers are in different timezones (so local time have huge difference). I'll try to temporary switch servers to the same timezone (not on business hours, so I can't try this right now).

Comment: @rvs Different timezone shouldn't matter. Was the client certificate signed at all? And is there any NAT happening?

Comment: yep, timezone does not matter, checked just to be 100% sure. Yes, certificate was signed and `puppetca --list` does not shows anything unsigned. There is nat happening on border firewall (external ip -> internal openvpn server ip), but there is no nat inside vpn, as openvpn server & puppetmaster are on the same host.

Comment: @rvs I just noticed something else, and edited my answer.

Comment: 10.10.0.123 is eth0's ip, 192.168.124.1 is openvpn's tun0 ip, so there is no nat, just another network interface

Comment: @rvs and does the name server0.fqdn solves to the IP 192.168.124.1 and vice versa on both client and server?

Comment: Well, '192.168.124.1 server0.fqdn' added to client's /etc/hosts, so it should resolve in both ways. But on server0, server0.fqdn resolves to 127.0.0.1, but there are no problems with other clients from 10.10.0.0/24 network. It still can be the problem?

Comment: @rvs But the other clients do access the `192.168.124.1` IP, do they?

Comment: No, all other clients are on 10.10.0.x network and access puppetmaster via 10.10.0.123 ip (specified on hosts file at the same way - we don't have internal dns yet).